# Click event not firing on first click

Tags: javascript, events, dom

My function wouldn't fire on first click, but it fires on second click.Why is that ? Here is my code.

```
const btn = document.querySelectorAll('#container div i');

btn.forEach(function(btn){

    btn.addEventListener('click', function(e){
      const iParent = e.target.parentElement.parentElement;

        iParent.removeChild(iParent.childNodes[0]);


    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You've misidentified the problem. It will fire on both clicks.

The first click will remove the first child of `iParent`. This is probably a text node containing only whitespace, so removing it has no visible effect.

Consider using `children` instead of `chidNodes`. It holds only elements instead of all kinds of nodes.